# adding a generic sorter expression for orderby statements

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

(I have simplified all code to only have the specific issue)

I have created a couple of different service methods that takes in a sort expression, which I want to use in an order by statement.

The 2 versions are as follows:

```
public List<Order> GetOrders(Expression<Func<Order, object>> sortExpression)
{
    // get the query for the orders table
    IQueryable<Order> query = GetQuery();

    // order by based on the passed in expression
    query = query.OrderBy(sortExpression);

    // now execute the query and return the collection
    return query.ToList();
}

public List<Order> GetOrders2(Func<IQueryable<Order>, IOrderedQueryable<Order>> orderby)
{
    IQueryable<Order> dbQuery = GetQuery();

    if (orderby != null)
    {
        dbQuery = orderby(dbQuery);
    }

    return dbQuery.ToList();
}
```

I call them with:

```
GetOrders(o => o.CreatedOnDate);
GetOrders2(queryable => queryable.OrderBy(o => o.CreatedOnDate));
```

The first method works fine if I only pass in certain types. If I pass in a `DateTime` or a `Nullable` type then it throws an exception that it cannot cast these types to an `object`.

The second method works fine if I pass in one sort expression. But if I try and pass in a collection (or params), the only way I can it to work is basically the last sort order overwrites the previous one.

How would I change one of these so that it takes in multiple sort expressions, it deals with `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`, and it works for all types?

Comment: I'd be surprised if that even compiled, considering your example appears to be providing a `Func<Order, DateTime>` but your method is taking a parameter of type `Func<IQueryable<Order>, IOrderedQueryable<Order>>`

Comment: Is there a `GetOrders` overload missing here?

Comment: ah I'll need to go back to that method. I had a few different versions trying loads of different things, and posted as I was rushing out for a meeting! I will update this question :S

Comment: Question updated, and yes, there was an overload missing :S

Answer (score 1):

So first off, if you want to provide just a lambda to `GetOrders` then you need to accept an `Expression<Func<Order, object>>` rather than what you have.

To accept any number of selectors, the most convenient (for the caller) is to use `params` on such an argument.

At that point it's simply a matter of ordering on the first selector and then calling `ThenBy` on all subsequent selectors.

```
public List<Order> GetOrders(params Expression<Func<Order, object>>[] selectors)
{
    var dbQuery = GetQuery();

    if (selectors.Any())
    {
        var orderedQuery = dbQuery.OrderBy(selectors.First());

        foreach (var selector in selectors.Skip(1))
            orderedQuery = orderedQuery.ThenBy(selector);
        dbQuery = orderedQuery;
    }

    return dbQuery.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Hi Servy. I tried that approach as my very first attempt. However, using Expression<Func<Order, object>> only worked for certain types. It doesn't work for DateTime, or Nullables, and I'm sure a few more. You get an error message, something about trying to cast from DateTime to object.

Comment: @eyeballpaul The only way you'll be able to support that is to have different overloads for each number of arguments you want to be able to support.  There's no way to have different generic arguments for a dynamic number of parameters.  Honestly though, at that point you're simply better off having the caller of the method call `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` explicitly, rather than trying to just pass the selectors.  You're not really saving them much of any work.

Comment: It is more because the query will be behind a service layer, so the front end (MVC) cannot do the filtering/sorting. I need to do all of that service side. And I want it working for everything, from paging, ordering and filtering. I can get the majority of it all working fine. The only issue that remains (I think) is the sorting like I described

Comment: @eyeballpaul In this case the method you're creating is resulting in the caller doing *more* work, and *still* using the LINQ `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` methods.  Just remove this method entirely.  It is adding negative value.  Have the caller simply call `GetQuery().OrderBy(o => o.Whatever).ThenBy(o => o.SomethingElse)`.  The method you're describing is no simpler/easier than them doing that, nor is it abstracting anything away from them.

Comment: The "GetQuery" is in the repository layer. The service layer sits above that and will be sitting on another server from the MVC layer. The return from the service layer will be something like "IList<Order>". The service layer can not return IEnumerable or IQueryable. The service layer will be dealing with when queries are run, not the front end.

Comment: @eyeballpaul Your service layer is adding literally negative value here.  Despite the fact that its method is returning an `IList`, your service layer is still the layer that is defining what the query is, not your repository layer.  It sounds like you're following some arbitrary "best practice" guidelines without regard for what solution is actually best for the situation you're in.  In an attempt to follow the guidelines that you're adhering to based on dogma, you are *harming* the quality of your application.

Comment: Ok. If we forget that there is a repository and service layer. Think of them as one. There is a service layer that does all the work. Returns IList. And the service layer needs a way to do paging/sorting/filtering. Totally abstracted away from the MVC layer. So the MVC layer would say, I want 20 records, ordered on "X" and filtered on "Y". Think about info the service layer may need to return for a grid.

Comment: @eyeballpaul So what information are you given, specifically?  If you have a programmer somewhere righting a lambda to define each of the fields to order on, then wherever that is they should be given an `IQueryable`, call their `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` calls, and pass the resulting query onto...wherever it needs to go.  In this case your `GetOrders` method is doing basically nothing more than invoking another lambda and calling `ToList` on it to prevent the query from being altered.  That means that wherever the lambda is defined is where all of the work is done.

Comment: The easiest way, would be for the service layer to take in a full query, or return one. But that gives almost full control to the front end. I need full control to be on the back end. So I tell anyone on the front end to tell me the exacts that they need. They would get a cut down version, based on page sizing etc, and in the order for that to work for them, they would need to also provide a sorting. Previously, all I would let them do, is tell me which page they require. I am now opening that up, to allow the functionality to choose the order etc.